# Microsoft ad blocks all links other than on the ad

Tags: bug, advertising

Today I have a weird issue with this Microsoft ad:

[image]

As soon as this ad was loaded (which takes its time) I can not click on any other links on this tab. Before the ad was loaded everything is as expected. Links on other tabs are not affected.

This is the link on the ad:

```
http://pixel.mathtag.com/click/img?mt_aid=2053373202359547733&mt_id=4058991&mt_adid=166373&mt_sid=2162861&mt_exid=15&mt_inapp=0&mt_uuid=9fe0592d-1573-4d00-bc86-a60335efa8cf&mt_lp=https%3A//azure.microsoft.com&redirect=https://ad.atdmt.com/c/go;p=11087213775293;as=0;a=11087213780562;crs=11087210909055;cr=11087210909105;i.ts=1496298071
```

My further investigation revealed that it is left mouse clicks only that are affected. Opening links with the right click context menu and the link from `1 question with new activity` work fine.

This is the source code on my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><style>div,iframe { top: 0; position:absolute; }</style></head><body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;"><script type="text/javascript">var divName = "adzerk337324567";var inFIF=true;var inDapIF = true;</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://a1611.casalemedia.com/pcreative?au=4&c=A6F102&pcid=F2D201195E00&pr=xx&r=F2D20119&s=29C4E&t=592FB255&u=VjROMFA3bFFKMTRBQUJVaVREa0FBQUNV&m=cbf8c99fa475b0b916ffd39802f00ff5&wp=2BE8&cp=3.48&aid=5A85C54325F4ED92&tid=EF14&dm=64&d=9099&n=askubuntu.com&epr=20267976ed204843a2b732e8eae6ff17"></script></body></html>
```

Paradoxically the issue occured on I.E. 11 on Windows 7 (no ad blocker installed) that I have to use here. I don't mind SE to make some earnings from ads but they probably should not behave in such a way.

Comment: I've identified the campaign in question, digging to try to repro and QA if possible.

Comment: @stevvve: thanks. Now at home on Ubuntu Chromium the ad is a different one (no issues there).

Comment: Yeah right now we're having a difficult time even seeing that specific ad (even in our ad server), let alone reproducing the issue.

Comment: Added a link and source to the MS ad as of today - same issues than before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client in question made it very clear they take issues like this very seriously. Our contact attempted to reproduce this issue in multiple environments and checked reporting to confirm delivery looked normal as well. In addition, they also checked impressions/loads of this creative in their DSP and failed to find any issues.

This appears to be user-specific and cannot be QA'd any further on our end. That said, if this continues to affect your ability to use the site, please let us know and provide any additional details you can.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It may then be a configuration issue of the computers we have at my work place that accidentally affects this single campaign.

Comment: No problem! I am really impressed with the client on this one. They dug more than most I've seen. Good to know they care about issues like this as much as we do!